# How to retain control field values after clicking browser back angular 2

Tags: angular, browser, back

I have two pages . Main page and Details page . When I click View details from main page, it navigates to Details page through routing. I am trying to preserve the field values even after the click of browser back from details page to main page. Right now the field values are getting cleared.Is there anyway to retain the field control values?

Comment: Try preserving data in a **service** that is **shared** between those two components.

Comment: you get reference from here..https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d

Comment: my question entirely different. I have entered some field values in main page and I am navigating to detail page. When i come back from detail page to main page , the values entered in main page are cleared

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I can think of that might work is creating a custom component and initializing it in your main page, then using this component to store form information, as the main page is a the bottom of routing, it won't disappear when routing to details page.

Comment: Can u provide a sample

Answer (score 0):

You can use guards to prevent navigation away until the values are saved or the user has chosen to discard the values. You could temporarily (automatically) store the values on the server, in cookies, or in local storage. However, retaining values in a form which has gone out of scope is "unusual" and is probably not a best practice